# What are the best practices for moving macOS App(s) to an external drive?

Tags: macos, external-disk, storage, core-storage

I'd like to free up space on my mac's internal HD. I currently run with no external HDs.

Seems like one option is to selectively move one or more apps (that I don't use very much), along with their associated libraries, from internal HD to external HD `EHD`.

For the sake of the goals/criteria below, let's say (a) I'm not moving any `/Users/*`, and (b) `EHD` is an external SSD connected via USB-2.

For any such low-use app `App` which is currently wholly-contained on my internal HD, I'd like to know how to move it to `EHD` such that:

- if `EHD` is mounted/available, then startup or access times for `App` are not a primary concern (slow is ok)
- I'm in control of `EHD`'s mounting/availability (so if `EHD` isn't mounted, it means that I don't care about `App`'s availability)
- **key goals**:

  - keep macOS on internal HD
  - don't move `/Users/*`
  - regardless of whether or not `EHD` is mounted, any operations NOT associated with `App` (or its libraries) should have same functionality and performance as they currently do.

I've looked at some old-ish SO questions ([Photos.App/Mail.App](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/351524/best-practices-to-move-macos-mail-app-storage-to-an-external-drive), [IBooks.App](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/130207/moving-ibooks-library-to-an-external-drive)) which seem pretty similar to what I'm asking, but I'm looking for more general how-to/best-practice recommendations/gotcha's. I reckon that a naïve approach would be to just drag `App.app` from `/Applications/App.app` to `EHD/wherever/`, but I'm hoping for something less naïve.

For what it's worth, my first target for `App` is XCode -- seems to take up alot of disk space, and I don't use it much, but would like freedom to power it up (over possibly painfully-slow USB) when necessary.

Comment: Why don't you just try moving the app? One way or the other it need to get to the external drive :-)

Comment: Usually just copying the app works. I have done that myself, but not with Xcode, rather with games or just large applications in general. Speed should not be an issue here, if it is, then it is the USB 2 connection bottlenecking...

Comment: @nohillside - because I found 15,427 files with "Xcode" in their name in /Users/ME/Library/**. I didn't know/suspect "just moving the app" would handle all of those dependencies.

Comment: @X_841 'copy' sounds less intrusive than 'move' -- I'll give it a shot, thanks!

Comment: The dependency is to your Library which doesn't move so Xcode still should find what it needs. The files in your Library will not be moved of course :-)

Comment: To add to @nohillside, they will not be moved and **should** not be moved, otherwise Xcode won't work properly. There are ways around that by creating symlinks, but I prefer not using these.

Comment: Thanks folks -- seems that I asked a bad question. For a given app, what could possibly be a space-saver is if one were to move not only X.app, but also X.app's libraries. In the case of my installation of Xcode, I'm seeing 9.3G in /Applications/Xcode.app, and 11G in /Users/ME/Library/Developer/Xcode folder (https://pastebin.com/b7E0vafw).

So for my Xcode, simply moving the app will save me a significant amount of disk space -- cool!

I'll work on formulating a better "how to move X.app + its dependencies in /Library/../X" question.

Comment: *Some* apps won't want to run from alternate locations, the only way to find out is to try it. Also its a **really bad idea** to move the libraries, those should be left alone as the app will be looking for them in a specific location and unless you plan on symlinking everything (possibly worth a try if you make sure you can put everything back) that the app is looking for. Any app that installs by just dragging the icon to the /Applications folder should work this way. Default macOS Apps and apps with installers may be problematic or down right impossible.

Comment: @SteveChambers - thanks for digging through the comments to find my embedded/implicit follow-up question regarding libraries.